# OpenCV Memory and CPU Usage

Tags: python, opencv, ros, nvidia-jetson

I'm making a USV (Unmanned Surface Vehicle) for my bachelor project. The track it needs to keep is made by having coloured buoys on the left/right side of the track and for obstacles.
So I need to track the depth of these objects and give all that information on to my navigation program.

And I have made a Python code using ROS and OpenCV to track these buoys with a ZED2 camera. But I'm having CPU and memory issues. Where the ubuntu desktop starts to lag.
Using a Nvidia Jetson Xavier NX and I’m using 85% of the CPU and 5,5+/7.59Gb Memory.

Anyone interested in looking over my code and see if I'm doing something stupid. That would explain my issues.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import roslib
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from main.msg import VarRed, VarGreen, VarYellow, RedHSV, GreenHSV, YellowHSV, MidPoint
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
from collections import deque
import math

class image_converter:
    def __init__(self):

        self.image_subd = rospy.Subscriber("/zed2/zed_node/depth/depth_registered",Image,self.callbackDepth)
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/zed2/zed_node/rgb_raw/image_raw_color",Image,self.callbackVideo)
        
        self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("/Tracking/RG_image", Image, queue_size = 1)

        self.RedHSV_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/Tracking/Red_HSV", RedHSV, self.redHSV)
        self.GreenHSV_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/Tracking/Green_HSV", GreenHSV, self.greenHSV)
        self.YellowHSV_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/Tracking/Yellow_HSV", YellowHSV, self.yellowHSV)

        self.MidPoint_pub = rospy.Publisher("/Tracking/MidPoint", MidPoint, queue_size = 1)

        self.red_bridge = CvBridge()
        self.red_publisher = rospy.Publisher("/Tracking/red", VarRed, queue_size = 1)

        self.green_bridge = CvBridge()
        self.green_publisher = rospy.Publisher("/Tracking/green", VarGreen, queue_size = 1)
                        
        self.yellow_bridge = CvBridge()
        self.yellow_publisher = rospy.Publisher("/Tracking/yellow", VarYellow, queue_size = 1)

        self.RedLower =  (0, 101, 68)                                                                                # Declaring the red-specter
        self.RedUpper = (15, 255, 255)

        self.GreenLower =  (75, 145, 48)                                                                               # Declaring the green-specter
        self.GreenUpper = (96, 255, 75)

        self.YellowLower =  (28, 56, 91)                                                                            # Declaring the yellow-specter
        self.YellowUpper = (51, 152, 150)


        self.red_pts = deque(maxlen=14)
        self.currentDepthImg=0
        self.red_counter = 0
        self.red_x = 0
        self.red_y = 0
        self.red_radius = 30

        self.green_pts = deque(maxlen=14)
        self.green_currentDepthImg=0
        self.green_counter = 0
        self.green_x = 0
        self.green_y = 0
        self.green_radius = 30

        self.yellow_pts = deque(maxlen=14)
        self.yellow_currentDepthImg=0
        self.yellow_counter = 0
        self.yellow_x = 0
        self.yellow_y = 0
        self.yellow_radius = 30

    def redHSV(self,msg):
        self.RedLower = (msg.r_h_low-10, msg.r_s_low-10, msg.r_v_low-10)
        self.RedUpper = (msg.r_h_high+10, msg.r_s_high+10, msg.r_v_high+10)

    def greenHSV(self,msg):
        self.GreenLower = (msg.g_h_low-10, msg.g_s_low-10, msg.g_v_low-10)
        self.GreenUpper = (msg.g_h_high+10, msg.g_s_high+10, msg.g_v_high+10)

    def yellowHSV(self,msg):
        self.YellowLower = (msg.y_h_low-10, msg.y_s_low-10, msg.y_v_low-10)
        self.YellowUpper = (msg.y_h_high+10, msg.y_s_high+10, msg.y_v_high+10)

    def callbackDepth(self,msg_depth):
        try:
            cv_image_depth = self.red_bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg_depth, "32FC1")                                        # CV_Bridge Depth
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
            return

        self.currentDepthImg=cv_image_depth

        try:
            a=1
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
            return
            
    def callbackVideo(self,data):
        try:
            cv_image = self.red_bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")                                                    # CV_Bridge Video
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
            return


        (rows,cols,channels) = cv_image.shape

        frame = cv_image
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (21, 21), 0)                                                                # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV (11,11), 0
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)                                                                # color space.
    
        red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, self.RedLower, self.RedUpper)                                                     # Construct a mask for the color "red", then perform
        red_mask = cv2.erode(red_mask, None, iterations=2)                                                            # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small 
        red_mask = cv2.dilate(red_mask, None, iterations=2)                                                           # blobs thats left in the mask.

        green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, self.GreenLower, self.GreenUpper)                                               # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
        green_mask = cv2.erode(green_mask, None, iterations=2)                                                        # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
        green_mask = cv2.dilate(green_mask, None, iterations=2)                                                       # blobs thats left in the mask.    

        yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, self.YellowLower, self.YellowUpper)                                            # construct a mask for the color "yellow", then perform
        yellow_mask = cv2.erode(yellow_mask, None, iterations=2)                                                      # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
        yellow_mask = cv2.dilate(yellow_mask, None, iterations=2)                                                     # blobs thats left in the mask.   

        red_cnts = cv2.findContours(red_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)                      # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        red_cnts = imutils.grab_contours(red_cnts)
        red_center = None
        self.red_radius = 0

        green_cnts = cv2.findContours(green_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)                  # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        green_cnts = imutils.grab_contours(green_cnts)
        green_center = None
        self.green_radius = 0

        yellow_cnts = cv2.findContours(yellow_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)                # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
        yellow_cnts = imutils.grab_contours(yellow_cnts)
        yellow_center = None
        self.yellow_radius = 0

        cv_imaged=self.currentDepthImg
    



#-----------------------------------------RED_START------------------------------------------------------

        if len(red_cnts) > 0:                                                                                         # only proceed if at least one contour was found

            red_c = max(red_cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)                                                                # find the largest contour in the red_mask, then use
            ((self.red_x, self.red_y), self.red_radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(red_c)                               # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
            red_M = cv2.moments(red_c)                                                                                # centroid
            red_center = (int(red_M["m10"] / red_M["m00"]), int(red_M["m01"] / red_M["m00"]))


        if self.red_radius > 5:                                                                                       # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size

            cv2.circle(frame, (int(self.red_x), int(self.red_y)), int(self.red_radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)             # draw the circle and centroid on the red_frame,
            cv2.circle(frame, red_center, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)                                                         # then update the list of tracked points

            msg = VarRed()
            msg.r_visible = True
            #if self.red_y == self.red_y and self.red_x == self.red_x:
            r_length = cv_imaged[int(self.red_y),int(self.red_x)]                                                 # length to object
            msg.r_x = self.red_x
            msg.r_y = self.red_y
            msg.r_rad = self.red_radius


            ToRad = 2*np.pi/360      # = 0.01745329252
            ToDeg = 360/(2*np.pi)    # = 57.29577951308
                                  
            # Printing pixel values

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 0), (200, 190), (0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("L: %.3f" %r_length), ((int(self.red_x)),int(self.red_y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("RX: %.1f" %msg.r_x +" px"), (10,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("RY: %.1f" %msg.r_y + " px"), (10,60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)

            # For X-direction
            red_l_cm = (r_length*100)                                                                             # Converting to Centimeters
            start_x_r = 960/(math.tan((55*ToRad)))                                                                    # finding start x-length in px
            ang_x_r =  (math.atan((self.red_x-960)/start_x_r))*ToDeg                                                  # finding horizontal angle
            red_x_cm = (red_l_cm*math.sin((ang_x_r)*ToRad))

            cv2.putText(frame, str("RXC: %.1f" %red_x_cm + " cm"), (10,90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("X Ang: %.1f" %ang_x_r), (10,150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)

            # For Y-direction
            start_y_r = 540/(math.tan((35*ToRad)))                                                                              # finding start y-length in px
            ang_y_r = ((math.atan((self.red_y-540)/start_y_r))*ToDeg)*-1                                                        # finding vertical angle
            red_y_cm = (red_l_cm/math.tan((ang_y_r*ToRad)+(math.pi/2)))*-1                                                      # finding the y-length

            cv2.putText(frame, str("RYC: %.1f" %red_y_cm + " cm"), (10,120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("Y Ang: %.1f" %ang_y_r), (10,180), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)

            red_z = (math.cos(abs(ang_x_r)*ToRad))*red_l_cm

            self.red_pts.appendleft(red_center)
            msg.r_length = red_l_cm
            msg.r_xc = red_x_cm
            msg.r_yc = red_y_cm
            msg.r_angle = ang_x_r                                                                                     # update the points queue
            msg.r_z = red_z            
            self.red_publisher.publish(msg)

            for i in range(1, len(self.red_pts)):                                                                     # loop over the set of points
                                                                                                                      
                if self.red_pts[i - 1] is None or self.red_pts[i] is None:                                            # if either of the tracked points
                    continue                                                                                          # are None, ignore them.

                thickness = int(np.sqrt(64 / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)                                                     # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
                cv2.line(frame, self.red_pts[i - 1], self.red_pts[i], (0, 255, 255), thickness)                         # draw the connecting lines

        if self.red_radius < 5:
            msg = VarRed()
            msg.r_visible = False
            self.red_publisher.publish(msg)
        
#-----------------------------------------RED_END------------------------------------------------------



#-----------------------------------------GREEN_START------------------------------------------------------

        if len(green_cnts) > 0:                                                                                       # same as in red, but for green

            green_c = max(green_cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            ((self.green_x, self.green_y), self.green_radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(green_c)
            green_M = cv2.moments(green_c)
            green_center = (int(green_M["m10"] / green_M["m00"]), int(green_M["m01"] / green_M["m00"]))


        if self.green_radius > 5:

            cv2.circle(frame, (int(self.green_x), int(self.green_y)), int(self.green_radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, green_center, 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)
            ToRad = 2*np.pi/360      # = 0.01745329252
            ToDeg = 360/(2*np.pi)    # = 57.29577951308

            msg1 = VarGreen()
            msg1.g_visible = True
            g_length = cv_imaged[int(self.green_y),int(self.green_x)]   
            msg1.g_x = self.green_x
            msg1.g_y = self.green_y
            msg1.g_rad = self.green_radius

            # Printing pixel values

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (1740, 0), (1920, 200), (0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("L: %.3f" %g_length), ((int(self.green_x)),int(self.green_y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("GX: %.1f" %msg1.g_x +"px"), (1740,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("GY: %.1f" %msg1.g_y + "px"), (1740,60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)

            
            # For X-direction
            green_l_cm = (g_length*100)
            start_x_g = 960/(math.tan((55*2*np.pi/360)))
            ang_x_g = (math.atan((self.green_x-960)/start_x_g))*57.295779513
            green_x_cm = (green_l_cm*math.sin((ang_x_g)*ToRad))

            # For Y-direction
            start_y_g = 540/(math.tan((35*2*np.pi/360)))
            ang_y_g = ((math.atan((self.green_y-540)/start_y_g))*57.295779513)*-1
            green_y_cm = green_l_cm/math.tan(ang_y_g*ToRad+(math.pi/2))*-1


            cv2.putText(frame, str("GXC: %.1f" %green_x_cm + "cm"), (1740,90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("X Ang: %.1f" %ang_x_g), (1740,150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("GYC: %.1f" %green_y_cm + "cm"), (1740,120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
            cv2.putText(frame, str("Y Ang: %.1f" %ang_y_g), (1740,180), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)


            green_z = (math.cos(abs(ang_x_g)*ToRad))*green_l_cm
            self.green_pts.appendleft(green_center)
            msg1.g_length = green_l_cm
            msg1.g_xc = green_x_cm
            msg1.g_yc = green_y_cm
            msg1.g_angle = ang_x_g
            msg1.g_z = green_z
            self.green_publisher.publish(msg1)

            for i in range(1, len(self.green_pts)):                                                                   

                if self.green_pts[i - 1] is None or self.green_pts[i] is None:
                    continue

                thickness = int(np.sqrt(64 / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
                cv2.line(frame, self.green_pts[i - 1], self.green_pts[i], (0, 255, 255), thickness)

        if self.green_radius < 5:
            msg1 = VarGreen()
            msg1.g_visible = False
            self.green_publisher.publish(msg1)

        
#-----------------------------------------GREEN_END------------------------------------------------------


#-----------------------------------------YELLOW_START------------------------------------------------------
        if len(yellow_cnts) > 0:                                                                                      # only proceed if at least one contour was found

            yellow_c = max(yellow_cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)                                                          # find the largest contour in the yellow_mask, then use
            ((self.yellow_x, self.yellow_y), self.yellow_radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(yellow_c)                   # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
            yellow_M = cv2.moments(yellow_c)                                                                          # centroid
            yellow_center = (int(yellow_M["m10"] / yellow_M["m00"]), int(yellow_M["m01"] / yellow_M["m00"]))


        if self.yellow_radius > 5:                                                                                    # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size

            cv2.circle(frame, (int(self.yellow_x), int(self.yellow_y)), int(self.yellow_radius), (0, 0, 200), 2)    # draw the circle and centroid on the yellow_frame,
            cv2.circle(frame, yellow_center, 5, (0, 0, 200), -1)                                                      # then update the list of tracked points

            ToRad = 2*np.pi/360      # = 0.01745329252
            ToDeg = 360/(2*np.pi)    # = 57.29577951308

            msg2 = VarYellow()
            msg2.y_visible = True
            y_length = cv_imaged[int(self.yellow_y),int(self.yellow_x)]                                            # length to object
            msg2.y_x = self.yellow_x
            msg2.y_y = self.yellow_y
            msg2.y_rad = self.yellow_radius

            cv2.putText(frame, str("L: %.3f" %y_length), ((int(self.yellow_x)),int(self.yellow_y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,0,200), 2)

            # For X-direction
            yellow_l_cm = y_length*100                                                                    # Converting to Centimeters
            start_x_y = 960/(math.tan((55*2*np.pi/360)))                                                         # finding start x-length in px
            ang_x_y = (math.atan((self.yellow_x-960)/start_x_y))*57.295779513                                 # finding horizontal angle
            #yellow_x = yellow_l_cm/math.tan((ang_x_y/57.295779513))                                              # finding the x-length
            yellow_x_cm = (yellow_l_cm*math.sin((ang_x_y)*ToRad))


            # For Y-direction
            start_y_y = 540/(math.tan((35*2*np.pi/360)))                                                         # finding start y-length in px
            ang_y_y = ((math.atan((self.yellow_y-540)/start_y_y))*57.295779513)*-1                                 # finding vertical angle
            #yellow_y = yellow_l_cm/math.tan((ang_y_y/57.295779513))                                              # finding the y-length
            yellow_y_cm = yellow_l_cm/math.tan(ang_y_y*ToRad+(math.pi/2))*-1   

            yellow_z = (math.cos(abs(ang_x_y)*ToRad))*yellow_l_cm

            self.yellow_pts.appendleft(yellow_center)
            msg2.y_length = yellow_l_cm
            msg2.y_xc = yellow_x_cm
            msg2.y_yc = yellow_y_cm
            msg2.y_angle = ang_x_y                                                                               # update the points queue
            msg2.y_z = yellow_z
            self.yellow_publisher.publish(msg2)

            for i in range(1, len(self.yellow_pts)):                                                             # loop over the set of points
                                                                                                                      
                if self.yellow_pts[i - 1] is None or self.yellow_pts[i] is None:                                 # if either of the tracked points
                    continue                                                                                     # are None, ignore them.

                thickness = int(np.sqrt(64 / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)                                                # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
                cv2.line(frame, self.yellow_pts[i - 1], self.yellow_pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)              # draw the connecting lines

        if self.yellow_radius < 5: 
            msg2 = VarYellow()
            msg2.y_visible = False
            self.yellow_publisher.publish(msg2)

#-----------------------------------------YELLOW_END------------------------------------------------------
        try:

            if (self.green_radius > 5) & (self.red_radius > 5):                                                # if you can see both colors, proceed               
                ToRad = 2*np.pi/360      # = 0.01745329252
                ToDeg = 360/(2*np.pi)    # = 57.29577951308

                red_z = (math.cos(abs(ang_x_r)*ToRad))*red_l_cm
                green_z = (math.cos(abs(ang_x_g)*ToRad))*green_l_cm
                Delta_z = abs(red_z-green_z)
                Tot_x = abs(green_x_cm) + abs(red_x_cm)

                if Delta_z == Delta_z and Tot_x == Tot_x:
                    red_green_angle = (math.atan(Delta_z/Tot_x))*ToDeg
                    normal_angle =  red_green_angle
                
                    if green_l_cm >= red_l_cm:
                        normal_angle =  red_green_angle*-1
                    if green_l_cm < red_l_cm:
                        normal_angle =  red_green_angle

                    MidPoint_data = MidPoint()
                    MidPoint_data.angle = normal_angle
                    self.MidPoint_pub.publish(MidPoint_data)



                    length_between_x = math.sqrt((Tot_x*Tot_x)+(Delta_z*Delta_z))

                    Delta_y = abs(red_y_cm-green_y_cm)
                    length_between = math.sqrt((length_between_x*length_between_x)+(Delta_y*Delta_y))


                #dx = green_x_cm - red_x_cm                                                                    # Finding the space between the colors in x-direction
                #dy = green_y_cm - red_y_cm                                                                    # Finding the space between the colors in y-direction  


                                                                         # Calculating the direct length between the colors in cm
                
                #cv2.rectangle(frame, (500, 0), (680, 160), (0,0,0), -1)
                #cv2.putText(frame, str("Dist: %.1f" %length_between + " cm"), (500,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)

                #Middle_x = dx
                #Middle_y = dy

                MP_X = (msg1.g_x + msg.r_x)/2
                MP_Y = (msg1.g_y + msg.r_y)/2

                #Middle_Point_Angle = (math.atan((MP_X-960)/start_x_g))*57.295779513

                #Middle_Point_Angle = ang_x_g - ang_x_r

                #Middle_Point_Length =(red_x_cm-abs(Middle_x))/(math.sin((math.pi/2)-(Middle_Point_Angle*((2*math.pi)/720))))
                #Middle_Point_Length =((red_x_cm-abs(Middle_x))/(math.cos(Middle_Point_Angle*((2*math.pi)/720))))

                #cv2.putText(frame, str("MX: %.1f" %Middle_x + " cm"), (500,60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
                #cv2.putText(frame, str("MY: %.1f" %Middle_y + " cm"), (500,90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
                if MP_X == MP_X and MP_Y == MP_Y: 
                    cv2.circle(frame, (int(MP_X), int(MP_Y)), 8, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                #cv2.putText(frame, str("M_L: %.1f" %Middle_Point_Length + " cm"), (500,120), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)
                #cv2.putText(frame, str("M_ang: %.1f" %Middle_Point_Angle), (500,150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 1)

                cv2.line(frame, (int(self.red_x),int(self.red_y)), (int(self.green_x),int(self.green_y)), (0, 0, 0), 2)

                #MidPoint_data = MidPoint()
                #MidPoint_data.z = Middle_Point_Length       
                #self.MidPoint_pub.publish(MidPoint_data)

            cv2.line(frame, (960, 1280), (960, 0), (0, 255, 0), 1)                    
            cv2.line(frame, (0, 540), (1920, 540), (0, 255, 0), 1)


            self.image_pub.publish(self.red_bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, "bgr8"))
            
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
            return

def main(args):
    ic = image_converter()
    rospy.init_node('Color_Tracker', anonymous=True)
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

[image: Image of code in action]

Comment: As a first step, refactor that giant function full of copy/pasted code. I mean, there are page-length sequences that seem to differ just in variable names. You have stuff like `ToRad = 2*np.pi/360      # = 0.01745329252` 4x in the same function... (even though numpy already provides functions for conversions between radians and degrees). | Once it's in a maintainable form, you can profile to identify the bottlenecks, and areas of high memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain further what you mean by "refactor it"? I have been looking for ways to shorten it because I`m aware I do the exactly same thing for three different colors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring -- take the repeated bits of code, and turn them into short functions, each performing some well-defined task. For example, the 3 lines that calculate `red_mask` could be turned into a function, which takes 3 parameters -- the HSV image, and lower and upper bound, and returns the mask. Since the mask is only used to find the contours, you could also merge the 2 contours specific lines, and just return contours instead. And so on.

Comment: Thank you. I`ll give that a try.

Comment: So is this what you mean? [Its not formating correctly]
`def masking(hsv,lower,upper):`
    `self._mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)`
    `self._mask = cv2.erode(self._mask, None, iterations=2)`
    `self._mask = cv2.dilate(self._mask, None, iterations=2)`
    `return self._mask`
`red_mask = masking(hsv, self.RedLower, self.RedUpper)`
`green_mask = masking(hsv, self.GreenLower, self.GreenUpper)`
`yellow_mask = masking(hsv, self.YellowLower, self.YellowUpper)`

Comment: Yes, although i'd just use a local variable instead of `self._mask`. Since you only assign to it, there's no benefit of having it persistent. You would have to make use of the optional "destination" parameter that many OpenCV functions support, but I would wait with that until the code is in a better shape.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your time and help.